# Did the reflexive case in Italian originate from Latin's passive case?

Tags: verbs, latin, infinitive, reflexive, passive

Did the reflexive case in Italian originate from Latin's passive case?

For example: *Farsi* (Latin: *fari*), *amarsi* (Latin: *amari*), etc.?

Rohlfs, [*Grammatica storica della lingua italiana*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6139) (vol. 2): *Morfologia* p. 186:

> 481. *Costruzione riflessiva con valore di passivo.* Tra le varie forme sostitutive che hanno preso il posto del defunto passivo latino, un ruolo particolare ha la costruzione riflessiva.

Comment: Please read the whole section of Rohlfs - it makes it clear that the *si passivante* is only a specific usage and has nothing to do with the generic reflexive voice. Moreover it is not saying it *derived* from the Latin passive, it's saying that (in certain contexts) it *replaced* it.

Comment: I might write a complete answer later today, since this is the only one of your questions that explains where you explain the background, and so it's much easier to answer